# preg_replace get only matched

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm having trouble with preg_replace and I'm not sure that I use correct function.

I'm usign function below in order to change youtube links into youtube embed videos. But I couldn't findout how I only get matched part and remove the rest?

I mean for instance :

http://www.vimeo.com/3124234&feature=1&v=1

when I use this function it's change to matched part an embed code. But I couldnt achieve to remove "&feature=1" part.

Should I use preg_replace for that or any other function can do what I'm trying?

Cheers

```
function convert_videos($string) {
    $rules = array(
'#http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/(\w+)?#i' => '<object width="450" height="320" data="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=$2&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1"></object>'
    );

    foreach ($rules as $link => $player)
        $string = preg_replace($link, $player, $string);


    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't match the entire string, and `preg_replace` will only replace what your pattern matches. You can use this pattern instead:

```
'#^http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/(\w+)(&.*)?$#i'
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` isn't part of `\w` that's it. I'd go with `\S` (not a space) instead.

```
#http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/(\S+)?#i
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: typo + backslash

You can use backreference for your (.*) values
in your case

```
#http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/(\w+)?#i
```

you can use \\1 for getting www. and \\2 for getting the values which you catch by (\w+)

or was this not what you want?

Comment: in fact I'm not good at regular expressions. I have long list for different video websites. for instance youtube :


'#http://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?v=([^ &\n]+)(&.*?(\n|\s))?#i'


I can't findout how can I ignore the rest of youtube link

Comment: I mean it could be something like :

'some words http://www.youtube.com/v?2413&feature=1 some other words'

I just want to ignore unmatched part